# Summarize number of cases in category and calculate new column

Tags: r, dplyr

I hava a dataset with the following structure

```
zip code |type of crime
------   |------
1002     |crime1
1002     |crime1
1002     |crime2
1002     |crime1
9210     |crime1
9210     |crime1
9210     |crime2
9210     |crime2
```

I also have a list of minimum sentences for each crime

```
crime |  minimum sentence (days)
------| ------
crime1|10
crime2|15
```

Using these two tables, I would like to do the following:

1. calculate the total of each crime in each neighborhood

   ```
   zip code | crime    |number of crimes
   ------   | ------   |-----
   1002     |  crime1  | 3
   1002     |  crime2  | 1
   9210     |  crime1  | 2
   9210     |  crime2  | 2
   ```
2. multiply each crime by it's minimum sentence and then calculate the total of days by neighborhood.

   ```
   zip  | crime  | crimexdays
   ---- | ------ | -----
   1002 | crime1 | 30
   1002 | crime2 | 15
   9210 | crime1 | 20
   9210 | crime2 | 30
   ```

I'd really appreciate any help here. Cheers!!

Comment: I think you can use `table`

Comment: Can you show the calculation for `crimexdays`?

Comment: Following your words instead of your numbers, `df %>% count(zip.code, type.of.crime) %>% mutate(crime.x.sentence = n * df2[df2$crime == type.of.crime, 2])`

Comment: thanks, akrun. Sorry I made a mistake in my original post and I corrected it already.  But to anwer the question: the minimum sentence for crime 1 is ten days. So there were 3 crime 1's in zip 1002. So crimexdays=30

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the frequency with `count`, `left_join` with second dataset and `trasmute` to create the new column

```
df1 %>% 
     count(zipcode, typeofcrime) %>% 
     left_join(., df2, by = c("typeofcrime" = "crime")) %>% 
     transmute(typeofcrime, crimexsentence = n*minimumsentence) 
#     zipcode typeofcrime crimexsentence
#     <int>       <chr>          <int>
#1    1002      crime1             30
#2    1002      crime2             15
#3    9210      crime1             20
#4    9210      crime2             30
```

Comment: just change to `crimexsentence = n * minimumsentence` maybe?